# Images not showing over SSL on apache2 with python script

Tags: python, html, ssl, apache2

I know this question has been asked several times, but I am all out of ideas and have been reading everywhere about this.

I am running Ubuntu 17.04 and Apache 2.4.25 to host a web server.  I have generated my own SSL certificate.  Since doing this, I am unable to view any images over SSL.  Currently, I can confirm the path is working, the file is in tact and URL is correct, as I can access this typing the http URL into my browser.

If I go to the web inspector whilst loading my site, if I click on any image it gives me a 404 error.

How do I get these images to load over SSL.

My apache2 config is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin info@****.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/****.com/pay
    Redirect /secure https://****.com/  


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/****.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/****.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

    SetEnv SECRET_KEY ****
    SetEnv PUBLISHABLE_**** 
    ServerAdmin info@****.com
    ServerName www.****.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/****.com/pay/static

    WSGIDaemonProcess webtool threads=5 python-path=/var/www/****.com/pay
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/****.com/pay/webtool.wsgi
    EnableMMAP off
    EnableSendfile off
    <Directory /var/www/****.com/pay>
    Options +ExecCGI
    WSGIProcessGroup webtool
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and I have a python script running to do my routes:

```
    import os
    import stripe
    import cgi
    print "Context-type: text/html"

    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, send_from_directory
    from flask import request
    from flask import json

    stripe_keys = {
        'secret_key': os.environ['SECRET_KEY'],
        'publishable_key': os.environ['PUBLISHABLE_KEY']
    }

    stripe.api_key = stripe_keys['secret_key']

    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html', key=stripe_keys['publishable_key'])


    @app.route("/hello")
    def hello():
        return "Hello World!"

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port="5050")

    @app.route("/charge", methods=['POST'])
    def charge():
         # Amount in cents
        amount = 500

        customer = stripe.Customer.create(
        email=request.form['stripeEmail'],
        source=request.form['stripeToken']
        )

        charge = stripe.Charge.create(
            customer=customer.id,
            receipt_email=request.form['stripeEmail'],
            amount=amount,
            currency='usd',
            description='Donation'
        )

        return render_template('charge.html', amount=amount)
```

I cannot work out if I need to set a route in my python script to allow images to be fetched, or I am missing something else.

I am calling the image in my index.html file with:

with the 'img' folder being in the same location as index.html.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your image requests are being sent to WSGI, if you want Apache to handle them, you'll have to "undo" the  WSGIScriptAlias of /.

I'm not a WSGI user, but it seems like you could block this from
running conditionally by putting this in your vhost:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^/img/ - [L]
```

Even though this is a no-op, it should block this part of WSGi from running.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I assumed this was probably the case and did some research into how to serve images in my flask app.  By creating a route to serve the images I was able to access these over SSL.

    @app.route("/static/<path:path>")         
    def images(path):
    return app.send_static_file(path)

Also apologies. I cannot get my comment to recognise my text as code. I have tried indenting four spaces as per the user guide.